# Why does an item with an expired Archive Date still appear in the Content Tree?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to create an Archive strategy within sitecore and I am seeing unexpected results. If I Archive an item manually, it goes to the Archive application and disapears from the Content Tree.

If instead, I set the Archive date and time and then wait, the item says in the archive menu "This item has been archived" but the item is still available in the content tree. It is also NOT available in the Archive application.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds as a pun, but the TaskDatabase takes over this task. :)

When you set an archive date on an item, the record about this gets into the Tasks table of the core database. Afterwards, the TaskDatabaseAgent iterates that table with the defined frequency and processes tasks. The frequency is defined as usual, in `<scheduling>` section of web.config.

The message "The item was archived at ..." should not confuse you - it is displayed once the date/time is reached. But the item will be archived the next time the scheduling agent runs the tasks database.

Play with scheduling settings and you'll see how it works.